# True or False question regarding least-squares solution

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

> If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then the equation $Ax = b$ has a unique least-squares solution for each $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $\det(AA^T)\neq 0$.

I believe it is true because if A is m x n matrix, then the equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for each $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ only if $A$ is invertible? My logic could be wrong so I am hoping for a second opinion.

Comment: Try some examples. Think of $A$ being a $2\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: For each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$? The equation $Ax=b$ only makes sense whenever $b$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Moreover, a system of linear equations may possess a unique solution even if $A$ isn't a square matrix.

Comment: Okay, yes I re-read the statement I believe you are right

Answer (score 1):

Even if we assume that $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$, then the statement is false. You can look at the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) which is the solution to the least-squares problem. The pseudo-inverse requires that
\begin{align}
A^{\mathsf{T}}A
\end{align}
be invertible; it says nothing about $AA^{\mathsf{T}}$.

An immediate counter-example is any column matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $\Vert{A}\Vert_{2}\neq 0$. In such case, $\operatorname{det}(AA^{\mathsf{T}})=0$ but $\operatorname{det}(A^{\mathsf{T}}A)=\Vert A\Vert_{2}^{2}\neq 0$, and the least-squares problem has a *unique* solution
$$
x^{\star} = (A^{\mathsf{T}}A)^{-1}Ab.
$$

On the other hand, you can have a row matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ such that $\Vert A^{\mathsf{T}}\Vert^{2}_{2}\neq 0$ which satisfies $\operatorname{det}(AA^{\mathsf{T}})\neq 0$ but doesn't satisfy $\operatorname{det}(A^{\mathsf{T}}A)\neq 0$, thus the pseudo-inverse $(A^{\mathsf{T}}A)^{-1}$ doesn't exist, which in turn implies that the least-squares solution is *not* unique.